# Why is php Websocket working on localhost but not on web hosting "siteground"

Tags: php, websocket

I developed a simple program using PhP websocket that works completely fine on localhost, however when I upload it to server the connection is not established.

I contacted the hosting team and they said there is a problem with the code.

### Server

```
<?php

define('HOST_NAME',"****.com");


 
define('PORT',"8080");
$null = NULL;

require_once("class.chathandler.php");
$Handler = new Handler();


$socketResource = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_set_option($socketResource, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
socket_bind($socketResource, 0, PORT);
socket_listen($socketResource);

// $socketResource = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
// socket_set_option($socketResource, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
// socket_bind($socketResource, HOST_NAME, 0) or die("Could not bind to socket\n");
// socket_listen($socketResource);
 

$clientSocketArray = array($socketResource);
while (true) {
    $newSocketArray = $clientSocketArray;
    socket_select($newSocketArray, $null, $null, 0, 10);
    
    if (in_array($socketResource, $newSocketArray)) {
        $newSocket = socket_accept($socketResource);
        $clientSocketArray[] = $newSocket;
        
        $header = socket_read($newSocket, 1024);
        $Handler->doHandshake($header, $newSocket, HOST_NAME, PORT);
        
        socket_getpeername($newSocket, $client_ip_address);
        $connectionACK = $Handler->newConnectionACK($client_ip_address);
        
        $Handler->send($connectionACK);
        
        $newSocketIndex = array_search($socketResource, $newSocketArray);
        unset($newSocketArray[$newSocketIndex]);
    }
    
    foreach ($newSocketArray as $newSocketArrayResource) {  
        while(socket_recv($newSocketArrayResource, $socketData, 1024, 0) >= 1){
            $socketMessage = $Handler->unseal($socketData);
            $messageObj = json_decode($socketMessage);
            
            $message = $Handler->createMessage($messageObj->id,$messageObj->message, $messageObj->value);
            $Handler->send($message);
            break 2;
        }
        
        $socketData = @socket_read($newSocketArrayResource, 1024, PHP_NORMAL_READ);
        if ($socketData === false) { 
            socket_getpeername($newSocketArrayResource, $client_ip_address);
            $connectionACK = $Handler->connectionDisconnectACK($client_ip_address);
            $Handler->send($connectionACK);
            $newSocketIndex = array_search($newSocketArrayResource, $clientSocketArray);
            unset($clientSocketArray[$newSocketIndex]);         
        }
    }
}
socket_close($socketResource);
```

### Handler

```
<?php
class Handler {
    function send($message) {
        global $clientSocketArray;
        $messageLength = strlen($message);
        foreach($clientSocketArray as $clientSocket)
        {
            @socket_write($clientSocket,$message,$messageLength);
        }
        return true;
    }

    function unseal($socketData) {
        $length = ord($socketData[1]) & 127;
        if($length == 126) {
            $masks = substr($socketData, 4, 4);
            $data = substr($socketData, 8);
        }
        elseif($length == 127) {
            $masks = substr($socketData, 10, 4);
            $data = substr($socketData, 14);
        }
        else {
            $masks = substr($socketData, 2, 4);
            $data = substr($socketData, 6);
        }
        $socketData = "";
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($data); ++$i) {
            $socketData .= $data[$i] ^ $masks[$i%4];
        }
        return $socketData;
    }

    function seal($socketData) {
        $b1 = 0x80 | (0x1 & 0x0f);
        $length = strlen($socketData);
        
        if($length <= 125)
            $header = pack('CC', $b1, $length);
        elseif($length > 125 && $length < 65536)
            $header = pack('CCn', $b1, 126, $length);
        elseif($length >= 65536)
            $header = pack('CCNN', $b1, 127, $length);
        return $header.$socketData;
    }

    function doHandshake($received_header,$client_socket_resource, $host_name, $port) {
        $headers = array();
        $lines = preg_split("/\r\n/", $received_header);
        foreach($lines as $line)
        {
            $line = chop($line);
            if(preg_match('/\A(\S+): (.*)\z/', $line, $matches))
            {
                $headers[$matches[1]] = $matches[2];
            }
        }

        $secKey = $headers['Sec-WebSocket-Key'];
        $secAccept = base64_encode(pack('H*', sha1($secKey . '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11')));
        $buffer  = "HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake\r\n" .
        "Upgrade: websocket\r\n" .
        "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" .
        "WebSocket-Origin: $host_name\r\n" .
        "WebSocket-Location: ws://$host_name:$port/demo/shout.php\r\n".
        "Sec-WebSocket-Accept:$secAccept\r\n\r\n";
        socket_write($client_socket_resource,$buffer,strlen($buffer));
    }
    
    function newConnectionACK($client_ip_address) {
        $message = 'New client ' . $client_ip_address.' joined';
        $messageArray = array('message'=>$message,'message_type'=>'connection-ack');
        $ACK = $this->seal(json_encode($messageArray));
        return $ACK;
    }
    
    function connectionDisconnectACK($client_ip_address) {
        $message = 'Client ' . $client_ip_address.' disconnected';
        $messageArray = array('message'=>$message,'message_type'=>'connection-ack');
        $ACK = $this->seal(json_encode($messageArray));
        return $ACK;
    }
    
    function createMessage($id,$message,$value) {
         
        $messageArray = array('id'=>$id,'message'=>$message,'value'=>$value);
        $TheMessage = $this->seal(json_encode($messageArray));
        return $TheMessage;
    }
}
?>
```

### Client

```
var websocket = new WebSocket("wss://*****.com:8080/PATH/server.php");
```

Locally I run

```
php -q server.php
```

or in the index I write

```
$lastLine = shell_exec("php q- server.php");
```

and it works perfectly both ways.

I tried to execute the server file on web server and it didn't work.
I logged in to my account via ssh and I tried to run the file from command line using

```
php -q server.php
```

or

```
nohup server.php
```

Both didn't work

### Strace

```
bind(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(80), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)

select(4, [3], [], [], {0, 10})         = 0 (Timeout)
```

After change the server code to

```
<?php

define('HOST_NAME',"*****.com");
$null = NULL;

require_once("class.chathandler.php");
$Handler = new Handler();

$socketResource = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
socket_set_option($socketResource, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
socket_bind($socketResource, HOST_NAME, 0) or die("Could not bind to socket\n");
socket_listen($socketResource);
```

the result of strace:

```
Process 28975 attached
restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted call ...>) = 0
fcntl(3, F_SETLKW, {type=F_WRLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=0, len=1}) = 0
fcntl(3, F_SETLK, {type=F_UNLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=0, len=1}) = 0
lstat("/home/customer/www/****-****.com/public_html/***/./class.chathandler.php", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2640, ...}) = 0
lstat("/home/customer/www/***-****.com/public_html/***/class.chathandler.php", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2640, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/customer/www/***-***.com/public_html/****/class.chathandler.php", O_RDONLY) = 4
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2640, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/customer/www/****-***.com/public_html/*****/class.chathandler.php", O_RDONLY) = 5
fstat(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2640, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2640, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 5, 0) = 0x7fa918f2a000
munmap(0x7fa918f2a000, 2640)            = 0
close(5)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/customer/.opcache/7.4.20-Jun  8 2021-07:38:48-7a502f21e059df70a79cf689ceb05dd9/home/customer/www/****-****.com/public_html/****/class.chathandler.php.bin", O_RDONLY) = 5
flock(5, LOCK_SH)                       = 0
read(5, "OPCACHE\0007a502f21e059df70a79cf689"..., 80) = 80
read(5, "\30\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\0\0@\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 14720) = 14720
flock(5, LOCK_UN)                       = 0
close(5)                                = 0
fcntl(3, F_SETLKW, {type=F_WRLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=0, len=1}) = 0
fcntl(3, F_SETLK, {type=F_UNLCK, whence=SEEK_SET, start=0, len=1}) = 0
close(4)                                = 0
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 4
setsockopt(4, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, [1], 4) = 0
stat("/etc/resolv.conf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=59, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/hosts", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 5
lseek(5, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
fstat(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=105, ...}) = 0
read(5, "127.0.0.1 localhost c25459 c2545"..., 4096) = 105
lseek(5, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 105
read(5, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(5)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 5
fstat(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=44304, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 44304, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 5, 0) = 0x7fa918ef5000
close(5)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib64/libnss_dns.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 5
read(5, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P#\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=39016, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 32776, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 5, 0) = 0x7fa914fa0000
mmap(0x7fa914fa2000, 16384, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 5, 0x2000) = 0x7fa914fa2000
mmap(0x7fa914fa6000, 4096, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 5, 0x6000) = 0x7fa914fa6000
mmap(0x7fa914fa7000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 5, 0x6000) = 0x7fa914fa7000
mmap(0x7fa914fa8000, 8, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa914fa8000
close(5)                                = 0
mprotect(0x7fa914fa7000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7fa918ef5000, 44304)           = 0
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, IPPROTO_IP) = 5
setsockopt(5, SOL_IP, IP_RECVERR, [1], 4) = 0
connect(5, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = 0
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 0)    = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLOUT}])
sendto(5, "\331N\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\***-****\3com\0"..., 36, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 36
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000)  = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLIN}])
ioctl(5, FIONREAD, [52])                = 0
recvfrom(5, "\331N\205\200\0\1\0\1\0\0\0\0\****-***\3com\0"..., 1024, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16]) = 52
close(5)                                = 0
bind(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(0), sin_addr=inet_addr("35.206.107.63")}, 16) = 0
listen(4, 0)                            = 0
select(5, [4], [], [], {0, 10})         = 0 (Timeout)
```

Comment: If you're on shared hosting there is no chance they will allow you to execute your own processes, or at least certainly not long running ones like a socket server. And/or you may not be allowed to open sockets / ports - that will be seen as a security risk. From their point of view you're just consuming extra resources. You need your own VPS where you can install and run whatever you like, or find a hosting package which has explicit support for this kind of thing.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. I actually contacted them and they blamed the code.

Comment: _"and they said there is a problem with the code"_ - Did they perhaps tell you what the problem was? Or did they just give you a blanket statement?

Comment: They only provided the log

Comment: Since it works locally, it's more likely that the environment is to blame IMO. Hosting companies do tend to avoid responsibility for this type of thing on the whole, if it's not a process they specifically support, they tend to just provide the infrastructure and then you have to figure everything else out yourself, unfortunately. In my experience the support staff usually have no programming experience, so will just blame your code for anything they don't understand.

Comment: Thank you. I already tried everything required so I guess the problem is from their side as you mentioned.

Comment: I have my doubts if this will work if you call the server with
`var websocket = new WebSocket("wss://*****.com:8080/PATH/server.php");`
Contacting the server via **wss**  is quite different from using  *ws*
How did you call the server on your local system ?

Comment: I used ws locally